# Heatmap of like against like (actuals not correlation coefficients)

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, correlation

In R I'm stuck on how to create the following table of data and chart.
I would like to take this set of data

| person_id | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | asthma |
| 1 | heart_disease |
| 1 | cancer |
| 2 | cancer |
| 3 | eczema |
| 3 | back_pain |
| 3 | cancer |
| 4 | asthma |
| 4 | back_pain |
| 4 | eczema |
| 4 | hypertension |
| 4 | diabetes |
| 4 | heart_disease |
| 5 | heart_disease |
| 6 | asthma |
| 6 | back_pain |
| 7 | heart_disease |
| 10 | asthma |

and organise it so it looks like this

[image]

where I have just done it for three medical conditions.

Then I'd like to create a  heat map to illustrate the data visually.  Something along these lines.
[image]

Any help would be gratefully received.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a heat map showing how often diagnoses occur together you could first `left_join` your data on itself by `person_id` and second use `count` to get the counts. Finally, you could use a `geom_tile` to create your heatmap.

Note: I dropped the diagonal row.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

dat |>
  left_join(dat,
    by = "person_id", 
    relationship = "many-to-many",
    suffix = c("1", "2")
  ) |>
  # Drop diagonal elements
  filter(
    Condition1 != Condition2, .by = person_id
  ) |>
  count(Condition1, Condition2) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Condition1, Condition2, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  person_id = c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 10L
  ),
  Condition = c(
    "asthma", "heart_disease",
    "cancer", "cancer", "eczema", "back_pain", "cancer", "asthma",
    "back_pain", "eczema", "hypertension", "diabetes",
    "heart_disease", "heart_disease", "asthma", "back_pain",
    "heart_disease", "asthma"
  )
)
```